# How to place Images(markers) inside a circle and make them clickable/touchable?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

What I want to do:

It should be something like a radar.
I send my geocoords to an API and get "people" back, and also their distance to me.

I have a round image as background, my radar screen, and I want to place a marker(another Image) on that image for every person I got back from the API.
In the center is my position and depending on the distance and direction, that marker should be placed.

While the radar is a circle I can´t work with normal coordinates(they would be a rectangle).
So my first question is, can you give me a pest practice or any advice how to do this?
Placing Bitmaps over Bitmaps?
But How to place them inside that circle?

On top of that, i want that markers to be clicked/touchable.
If two or more markers are really near togehter, so that you cant touch/click them seperatly, I need a way to find out, which markers are clicked/touched.
Or maybe in other words, which markers are placed inside the touched/clicked area.

How should I implement this?

Maybe android offers something I don´t think of (hopefully).

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a custom view that fits your your case... for example:

```
public class RadarView extends View {
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // draw the background
        // draw each dots.
    }
}
```

Of course the view will have to have a list of all the dots to press, as well as their positions.